# Testing local online application on actual mobile device with dynamic IP address

Tags: android, windows, mobile, localhost

Im currently developing a number of online applications with mobile friendly interfaces and would like to test them on my mobile device without having to upload (having problems with my internet connection)

Ive researched and seen there's a way it can be done with static IPs but since my internet connection requires an automatically assigned IP. Can this procedure also be done with a dynamic IP

My nachine and device specs are
Windows 10 64bit
Android 4.4.2

Xampp/Apache

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of achieving this

**1) Server behind router**

In this approach, you simply use your home/work Wi-Fi to connect to the server, hooked in to the same network. Later on, buy a domain/sub-domain and publish there.

**2) Server beyond router**

This will require some hacking in most cases. There are websites out there that provide dynamic DNS options. Almost all after-market router firmwares will support registering on to (many of) such websites. And then do [port-forwarding](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjABahUKEwj92IDssvvIAhWEMqYKHYDPCww&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FPort_forwarding&usg=AFQjCNFKJtGtutP5ukiO6JCmkWOmeMU9jQ&sig2=_HeAjrA8vpN_6KWv0hZxDA) to the server behind the router. In essence, you're asking for someone on the outside, to redirect traffic to (your) server, which is on the inside(behind the router).

Comment: @Stanley , I'm assuming you've already eliminated option #1 I've mentioned?

Comment: Yeah option one is problematic due to ny internet being very unreliable.

Comment: @StanleyNgumo - Actually #1 doesn't deal with internet connection at all. It's your own set up of Wi-Fi, which has to be very reliable. So, I'm now a little confused as to why you've eliminated local network setup. Do you have a router in your own control that you could connect both server and mobiles to?

Comment: aaahh I get what you mean!!!! Let me try it out and will let you know I misunderstood the solution.

Comment: Glad to know.. Any luck?